# Am I overthinking this simple power supply connection?

Tags: power-supply, basic

I want to connect a 12V fan and a motorcontroller to this generic ac to 12v dc power supply. The motorcontroller is pulling around 25 amps, and the fan about 1.

I'm just wondering, should i add a resistor to the fan power lead, or something to "protect" it. "Protect it from what?" you may ask, i dunno.

Just thinking here, if i should leave it as is. As i am using a different output, or maybe it is just 1 rail and i should do something to "protect" the weakest component.

I'm not very smart, any help or clarification is very welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a wild guess here and assume the the microcontroller draws 25mA and not 25A at 12VDC. And the fan 1A? Must be quite big.

You can go to town with protection (overvoltage, undervoltage, overcurrent, short-circuit, ESD, EMI... you name it).

When dealing with small currents like that you can connect them directly. A fuse (properly sized of course) will protect your conductors against short-circuits or overcurrent. But most of the switching power supplies like the one in the picture have short-circuit protection. If the output of your power supply is a couple of Amperes you don't need to worry about cable sizes or short-circuit currents.

In conclusion protection is good but you need to know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a resistor to protect it.

You do need to make sure the current output of your power supply can handle the current requirements which are 25A + 1A so 26A, plus some margin.

For a 12V power supply that would require 312W net output. Taking a 90% conversion efficiency, a 350W power supply or higher would be required.

Based on your picture it's a 400W power supply, so you can just connect everything as you drew, there should be no issue at all.